# Github push fails due to the file size larger than 100MB

Tags: git, github

I have a directory with many files and initially, I up it to the `Github` repo. Now, I added few more files and some docs as well and would like to push the rest of them as well.

Eventually, I could not do it as some file size is larger than 100MB. I use the terminal `find . -type f -size +100M` and find the files which are larger than the defined size of 100 MB. I get the output in the terminal,

`./.git/objects/09/e87222cb6921f6ea237546eb2d58cf5fc69967
./.git/objects/a2/cc9d29f717cca395741f49d437f98b149aab42
./Spring_Hibernate_Chad_Darby/Spring_Hibernate_Beginner.docx`

I have no idea about the first 2 files though and it doesn't matter if I could not up to these 3 files in the `Github`, the rest of the files will do just fine.

Say, how can I filter and up rest of the files in the `Github`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import git repositories with large files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986291/how-to-import-git-repositories-with-large-files)

Comment: Yes, little complicated for me to understand though

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/7976758